# Not able to access data in controller from factory

Tags: angularjs

I am developoing my first angular application.But I am not able to access data in controller which is coming from service.
service code is as follows.

var BASE= " https://abc.com/";

```
loginApp.factory('authFactory',function ($http,$location){
    var factory ={};
    factory.login= function (username ,password){

        var loginData='{"emailId":"'+username+'","password":"'+password+'"}';

        return $http({ url: BASE+'/login' ,
                       method: "POST",
                       data:  loginData
            }).success(function (results) {
                console.log("in service" +results.token );
                return results;
            }).error(function () {
                 console.log("error occured");
                 var err = "error";
                 return err;
        });
    };
    return factory;
});
```

My controller code is as follows.

```
loginApp.controller ('LoginController',function ($scope, $rootScope, $location,authFactory){
            $scope.submit= function (){
                    authFactory.login($scope.username, $scope.password).then(function (status) {
                        console.log("status is" +status.token);
                    });
            };

});
```

My problem is I am able to access results.token from service but If I tried to access same token from controller as status.token , it is giving "undefined".Please help to resolve this.

Comment: What is your serverside code?

Comment: Can you log just the `status` or is that undefined as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just return the $http promise, handle it in your controller:

In service:

```
return $http({ url: BASE+'/login' ,
                   method: "POST",
                   data:  loginData
        });
```

In Controller:

```
authFactory.login($scope.username, $scope.password)
.success(function(status) {
                    console.log("status is" +status.token);
                });
```

Comment: An important component of answering this issue (which is common for people new to Angular and promises) is explaining that `$http` uses promises for managing async requests. So when `login` returns using  `return $http(...)`, it's going to return a _promise_, which the controller can hook into to retrieve the resulting value using your example above. New folks frequently do what OP did above and think that returning from their `.success` function is going to make `login` return the result of the response. That is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is an REST-based and promise-based angular module [Restangular](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular), which let you easily write some service to communicate your APIs. For instance, in your cases:

```
myModule.factory('authFactory', ['Restangular',
  function(Restangular) {
    return {
      login: function(name, password) {
        // post /login
        return Restangular.all('login').post({"emailId":"'+name+'","password":"'+password+'"});
      }
    };
  }
]);
```

Update: In your controller, you should add this code at the end to invoke the function

```
$scope.submit();
```

Comment: While Restangular is a beautiful library that I also use myself, this does not address the problem. You should also explain how to get that data to the controller